# DrawImg on canvas takes more clicks to draw

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

It's a tic tac toe game using canvas, used the onclick and draw image when clicked but sometimes it needs more than 2 clicks to draw the image I think it's because the other functions are outside the $(function()...) but puting them in cause errors .Sorry I'm new.

```js
$(function(){
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(200,0);ctx.lineTo(200,600);ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(100,0);ctx.lineTo(100,600);ctx.stroke(); //Lineas deljuego
    ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(0,100);ctx.lineTo(600,100);ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(0,50);ctx.lineTo(600,50);ctx.stroke();
    
});

var turns=0;

function marcar(e){    
    var x= e.pageX;
    console.log(e.pageX);
    var y= e.pageY;
    cuadranteX=0;
    cuadranteY=0;
    if(x>=7&&x<=203)
        cuadranteX=0;
    else{
        if(x>=211&&x<=404)
            cuadranteX=105;
        else
            cuadranteX=205;
    }
    if(y>=7&&y<=198)
        cuadranteY=0;
    else{
        if(y>=212&&y<=398)
            cuadranteY=53;
        else
            cuadranteY=105;
    }
    console.log(e.pageY);
    console.log(cuadranteX);
    console.log(cuadranteY);
    draw(cuadranteX,cuadranteY);
}

function draw(x,y){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    if(turns%2==0)
        img.src ="./img/blackcat.png"
    else
        img.src ="./img/whitecat.png"
    ctx.drawImage(img,x,y,90,45);  
    console.log("pintado");
    turns++;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" onclick="marcar(event)"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML.

Comment: In the body it's only     `<canvas id="canvas" onclick="marcar(event)"></canvas>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing to draw the image:

```
    var img = new Image();
    if(turns%2==0)
        img.src ="./img/blackcat.png"
    else
        img.src ="./img/whitecat.png"
    ctx.drawImage(img,x,y,90,45);
```

... that does not guarantee the image has been fully loaded,
look at some examples of how to use that correctly:
https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/reference/drawimage.html

---

But for something this simple I would not use images, just draw a letter ( **X** or **O** ).
And your math/if conditions are overly complicated for this, see sample below

```js
let size = 60 // square_size
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.height = size * 3;
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '48px serif';

ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(size*2,0); ctx.lineTo(size*2,size*3); ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(  size,0); ctx.lineTo(  size,size*3); ctx.stroke(); 
ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(0,size*2); ctx.lineTo(size*3,size*2); ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();ctx.moveTo(0,  size); ctx.lineTo(size*3,  size); ctx.stroke();

var turns=0;

function marcar(e){    
    var x= e.pageX;    
    var y= e.pageY;
    cuadranteX = Math.floor(x / size) % 3;
    cuadranteY = Math.floor(y / size) % 3;    
    draw(cuadranteX,cuadranteY);
}

function draw(x,y){
    ctx.fillStyle = turns%2==0? "red": "blue"      
    ctx.fillText(turns%2==0? "X": "O", x*size + 10, y*size + 45)    
    turns++;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" onclick="marcar(event)"></canvas>
```

Comment: Using `ctx.fillText` worked better, thank you